# Filter JS array based on same values in a sequence

Tags: javascript, filter, iteration

I've an array like this.

```
const cars = [
  {year: "2003", made: "BMW"},
  {year: "2004", made: "Honda"},
  {year: "2005", made: "BMW"},
  {year: "2006", made: "BMW"},
  {year: "2006", made: "Mercedes"},
  {year: "2007", made: "BMW"},
  {year: "2008", made: "Mercedes"},
  {year: "2009", made: "Mercedes"},
];
```

An expected output:

```
const output = [
  [
    {year: "2003", made: "BMW"},
  ],
  [
    {year: "2004", made: "Honda"},
  ],
  [
    {year: "2005", made: "BMW"},
    {year: "2006", made: "BMW"},
  ],
  [
    {year: "2006", made: "Mercedes"},
  ],
  [
    {year: "2007", made: "BMW"},
  ].
  [
    {year: "2008", made: "Mercedes"},
    {year: "2009", made: "Mercedes"},
  ],
];
```

I hope the requirements are already clear from above code snippets. The main idea is to create an array object or multi dimensional array from the existing data based on matching value of a key. In example above the `made` key is filtered.

Comment: and your try? what does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce` and check if the previous made is equal to the current made then add to the same index or else push to the result

```js
const cars = [
    {year: '2003', made: 'BMW'},
    {year: '2004', made: 'Honda'},
    {year: '2005', made: 'BMW'},
    {year: '2006', made: 'BMW'},
    {year: '2006', made: 'Mercedes'},
    {year: '2007', made: 'BMW'},
    {year: '2008', made: 'Mercedes'},
    {year: '2009', made: 'Mercedes'},
];


let carsResult = [];
cars.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if (curr.made != prev.made) {
    carsResult.push([curr])
  } else {
    carsResult[carsResult.length - 1].push(curr)
  }
  return curr
}, {})
console.log(carsResult)
```

Comment: You saved my day <3, I don't get the logic of `carsResult.length - 1` why assigned the array key by decreasing 1 from length? Thanks

Comment: adding to the last index as their `made` was same